# A word for creepiness without reason?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, adjectives, synonyms

What would be **one word** for a deep-rooted, unsettling fear at a creepy place without any particular reason, just an unfounded, instinctive and unnatural feeling that something is not right, something to which the subject or the observer has no foresight into.

Comment: You already asked this question and it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The answer provided there is 'foreboding', which implies foresight and foreboding is hardly unfounded.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to explain "foreboding is hardly unfounded". Foreboding can simply be an apparently irrational sense of unease. Why does foreboding require foresight?

Comment: The _question_ is a duplicate. Note the body question is a SWR for 'I walked into the bar and felt  ______.  I knew something terrible was about to happen, but I couldn't place my finger on what, or why.' 'Foreboding' is usually defined without a 'fair reason' caveat.